# Is it possible to take over a WordPress site if the old administrator is MIA?

Tags: wp-admin, header-image

I do have a username and password, yet cannot make key changes through the dashboard.  For ex. I have not been able to change the site header image.  I've gone through the steps I've found online to how to do it, yet even though it shows that I've changed the header (via the dashboard), it has not effected the live site at all.  I am a total newbie to wordpress but am taking courses so I can help my friend with his non-profit.  The previous website administrator is no longer available and I cannot reach them.  I've also tried looking for the site on Github and cannot find. Website is pc4ih.org.  Any guidance would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: The reason why it won't show up is due to caching both server side (if the site is using a caching plugin) and locally in your browser. Clear both. For local, browswer cache, hold the shift key down while clicking the refresh icon (half circle with the arrow in the browser bar). You will have to look in your caching plugin docs to learn how to use it, probably a checkbox to turn it off and then save the settings. Turn it back on when you are done editing.

Comment: Thank you, Christina.  I did clear both browser and and wp caches and unfortunately, nothing has changed. I guess I'm just trying to understand what kind of changes can be easily made through the dashboard without any php or previous wp experience or whether I can't do anything without these first.

Comment: If you need to change the appearance of something, you would use CSS. If you need to add something that is in the header, footer, or not in the content area, you will need some php skills. The site header image could be added with php OR the customizer (Appearance > Customizer), or through CSS. You can upload a new one but the site won't reflect any change unless you point to the new file. Due to the way that WordPress organizes by date, you would not be able to upload a same named file because it is automatically put in a different directory for this month.

Answer (score 2):

If you have FTP access than you can set password with

```
wp_set_password('password', 1);
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_FTP
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password

or via database if you have access to phpMyAdmin according to http://www.devlounge.net/publishing/reset-a-wordpress-password-from-phpmyadmin

Comment: Thank you.  I do already have an administrator password.  I'm not able to change the header, regardless.  It shows in the dashboard as changed to the correct one, yet on the site, it shows the old header which says NMGH. The new one has the initials PCIH.  Very frustrated.

Comment: It's an image https://imgur.com/a/uDZhY that might be part of the theme. It could be hardcoded in `wp-content/themes/the-cause/header.php`